# Weird error when writing to a file in Spring WebMVC

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc

I have created a webservice application using Spring WebMVC where I have an endpoint on my controller as follow:

```
@PostMapping(
            path = "append",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public String append(@RequestBody AppendRequest request){
        service.appendFile(request);
        return "OK";
    }
```

and the service is as follow:

```
@Value
private String destinationPath;

public void appendFile(AppendRequest appendRequest) {
        log.info("Incoming payload, filename: {}, total records: {}", appendRequest.getFilename(), appendRequest.getPayload().size());
        Path directory = Paths.get(destinationPath, appendRequest.getSubdirectory());
        if (!directory.toFile().exists()){
            boolean ret = directory.toFile().mkdirs();
            if(!ret)
                log.warn("Cannot create destination directory: {}", directory);
        }
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Paths.get(directory.toString(), appendRequest.getFilename()).toFile(), true));
            writer.write(String.join(System.lineSeparator(), appendRequest.getPayload()) + System.lineSeparator());
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("Exception while writing to destination file: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Store file failed");
        }
    }
```

the AppendRequest:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class AppendRequest {
    private String subdirectory;
    private String fileName;
    private List<String> payload;
}
```

I have tested this webservice for overnight with one client send a request to it periodically and it works okay (able to process many incoming append request smoothly), but today I add two new clients to send requests to the webservice  and now I got many 500 errors when trying to writing the file e.g :

```
INFO 2024-01-09 16:44:48,797 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] f.w.s.Service - Incoming payload, filename: 235081_XYZ_0.TXT, total records: 250 
ERROR 2024-01-09 16:45:29,599 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] f.w.s.Service - Exception while writing to destination file: D:\Test\Webservice\destination\subdir\235081_XYZ_0.TXT (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error) java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Test\Webservice\destination\subdir\235081_XYZ_0.TXT (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
```

(note that each client will not send request with same filename - it will always be different)
But some time later when it receiving request with the same filename, it throw no error.
What possibly be wrong here? And sorry if the exception error is short because I set it that way. Will try to get the longer exception message.

Comment: where is the file storage inside docker/kubernetes/pod or external hdd. If this is inside pod path may not exist.

Comment: its on internal hdd

Comment: @of32inc Why not setup some mock clients that can continuously upload test files till they invoke the error? Also, can you add more information about the kind of system the application is running on? For example, is it a VM, dedicated hardware, cloud, and are others applications accessing that directory or have permission to it?

Comment: Definitely seems like more of an issue with the system or drive than with the web (MVC) code.